# ASP.NET Core stored procedure not working in loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I want to use a stored procedure for DB query, it works for a single query, but in loop, it executes like in first loop iteration.

```
var getAutoResults = new List<List<Karat_getAutoData_Result>>();

foreach (var elem in meas)
{                 
    getAutoResults.Add(await _context.KaratGetAutoDataResults
                  .FromSql($"dbo.Karat_getAutoData @MeasurementId = {elem.MeasurementId}, @CalcRequestId = {null}")                        
                  .ToListAsync());
}
```

After this I get N times the same results, but all ids are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve it only like this. I'm just creating new context instance in each loop. I think this is bad idea, but it works.

```
var getAutoResults = new List<List<Karat_getAutoData_Result>>();
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestRecipesDBContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MY CONNECTION STRING");
foreach (var elem in meas)
{
 using (var localContext = new TestRecipesDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
 {
  getAutoResults.Add(await localContext.KaratGetAutoDataResults
               .FromSql($"dbo.Karat_getAutoData @MeasurementId={elem.MeasurementId},@CalcRequestId={null}")                                    
               .ToListAsync());
 }
}
```

Solution below more usefull, just need use **AsNoTracking()**:

`getAutoResults.Add(await localContext.KaratGetAutoDataResults
                   .FromSql($"dbo.Karat_getAutoData @MeasurementId=elem.MeasurementId},@CalcRequestId={null}")
                   .AsNoTracking()

                   .ToListAsync());`