# How to execute stored procedure in foreach loop using EF Core in .NET Core?

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a foreach loop as follows:

```
foreach (var p in results)
{
    string InputOne = year.ToString();
    char c = '0';
    string InputTwo = month.ToString().PadLeft(2, c); 

    List<Entity> data = new List<Entity>();

    SqlParameter Param1 = new SqlParameter("@Param1", "Month");
    SqlParameter Param2 = new SqlParameter("@Param2", p.Id);
    SqlParameter Param3 = new SqlParameter("@Param3", InputOne);
    SqlParameter Param4 = new SqlParameter("@Param4", InputTwo);

    string usp = "Schema.usp_spname @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4";
    data = _dbContext._sp_GetEmployeeAttendanceData.FromSql(usp, Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4).ToList();
}
```

I am getting the same data for all conditions while my database contains different data..

Please help me to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

the last line in your loop

> data =

is replacing the data variable in each iteration, so you will only ever get the last iteration in that **For Loop**.. You need to change it so that the (data =) part appends to a list instead.. If data is a list, you can use `data.AddRange()`

And this line `List<Entity> data = new List<Entity>();` needs to be moved outside of the loop

Comment: it did same execution....for every condition it still getting same data

Comment: Then I can only assume that the problem is in the stored procedure itself and not the code you have posted

Comment: @Tejas, how you overcome this problem ? I also have same problem with you.

Comment: @RobertPerry, I followed your instruction but query return from SQL Server only have same value for each rows. I also tried to track it by using SQL Server Profiler. In every execution, SQL server Profiler capture every single loop by different parameter ID that sent to SQL server. But, again, It only return same value for all those rows. Any, thought ?

Comment: @Tejas, this solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207538/asp-net-core-stored-procedure-not-working-in-loop